# How to ensure PyCharm runs AND compiles using Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, compiler-errors, pycharm, runtime-error

When I run my code I get "Unsupported class file major version 59", which suggests java 15 bytecode.

When I run "java -version" on my terminal I get Java version 1.8.0_271-b09

So I believe the issue is that PyCharm is compiling the application in Java 15 and then trying to run it in Java 8. What is more confusing is I don't even have Java 15 installed in my machine.

So the question is how do I ensure it compiles at Java 8 to begin with?

I've tried using the "Choose Runtime" plugin, but everytime I select JDK 1.8 it shuts down and throws an error saying "must be Java 11 or later"

I'm pretty exhausted by this issue and really could use help on this- thanks.

Comment: Do you compile a java program in PyCharm? Anyways, you need a JDK 8 and the `PATH` needs to point to it.

Comment: @dan1st Yea it's a python application, but I dont understand then why I'm getting "Unsupported class file major version 59" Which is a Java error, correct? 
Also My JAVA_HOME path is pointing to "library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home"

Comment: Actually to clarify it is a PySpark application that utilizes Java

Comment: What is the output of `javac -version`? Set your `PATH` to point to the `bin` directory of the jdk-8 before any other jdk.

Comment: @dan1st javac version outputs javac 1.8.0_271. When I use command “where java” it outputs “/usr/bin/java”. I added that to my $PATH variable but it still doesn’t change anything.

Comment: It seems like java 11 is required, then.